# how can i set data in method apex

Tags: apex

I want to send data to function i guess its want to List type but i couldnt change well in my method rather am not sure yet

**this is my error code: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void UpdateContactOwner(List) from the type anon**

```
List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
acc = [SELECT OwnerId,Name From Account where Cari_Grup_Kodu__c IN('CO') Limit 1];

integer i = 0;

    if(acc.size() > 0)
    {
        List <String> Names = new List <String>();
        List<String> OwnerIds = new List <String>();
        for (Account acc_i : acc)
        {
            Names.add(acc_i.Name);
            OwnerIds.add(acc_i.OwnerId);
          --->  UpdateContactOwner(Names[i]);
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }
```

**And Here Method**

```
public class EditRecordContacts {

public static string UpdateContactOwner(List<string> names)
{
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    contacts = [Select Contact.OwnerId From Contact Where Name= :names];
    string a = 'Yes';
    return a; 
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UpdateContactOwner(List<string> names)` accepts `List<String>` you are trying to provide just `String` in the form of `Names[i]`.

Move your code outside for loop and pass it just `Names` list, and that should do.

```
if(acc.size() > 0)
    {
        List <String> Names = new List <String>();
        List<String> OwnerIds = new List <String>();
        for (Account acc_i : acc)
        {
            Names.add(acc_i.Name);
            OwnerIds.add(acc_i.OwnerId);

            i = i + 1;
        }
        EditRecordContacts.UpdateContactOwner(Names);

    }`
```

Comment: firstly thanks but i try that already i took again same error :(

Comment: Updated snippet

Comment: There is also error in class ```EditRecordContacts```. Should be ```contacts = [Select Contact.OwnerId From Contact Where Name IN :names];```. Not ```=``` but ```IN```. @FurkanKuyular

Comment: Everybody thanks i found my problem i wrote this EditRecordContacts.UpdateContactOwner(Names[i]); in loop again because i want to send Names and OwnerID regular because i have 10 thousand records to change ownerName's